# Running a script to check for duplicated files- frustration mounting

Tags: bash, loops, directory

So I have this- where a script checks an input folder for duplicate files...but it just doesn't work for some reason and it's really starting to frustrate me...the syntax seems to be correct from what I've seen online

It just doesn't loop properly- since the echo is input only once, but the folder i'm testing this on has 3 files in it. I tried to change the $FOLDER bit in line 4 to an actual name like /stuff/* and stuff/* and just stuff 
The name of the folder I'm testing things on. Any idea?

```
FOLDER=$1
mkdir check

for FILE in $FOLDER;
do
echo $FILE


CHECKSUM=$(cksum $FILE|awk '{print $1}')
if [[ -e check/$CHECKSUM ]];then
echo Duplicate at $FILE
rm $FILE

else

touch check/$CHECKSUM
echo "check/$CHECKSUM"

fi
```

Comment: How about just using fdupes?

Comment: You are missing a `done` at the end. You don't need a semi-colon after `for file in...`. You should wrap all occurrences of $FILE in double-quotes in case any files have spaces in their names.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing pathname expansion against files. Perhaps you want:

```
for FILE in "$FOLDER"/*;
```

If you want to target files with specific extensions do:

```
for FILE in "$FOLDER"/*.ext;
```

It's also a good thing to test if the files are really files and not directories:

```
for FILE in "$FOLDER"/*; do
    if [[ -f $FILE ]]; then
```

If you want to recursively process files use a while read loop instead with `find`:

```
while IFS= read FILE; do
    ...
done < <(exec find "$FOLDER" -type f)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Published under GPLv3. Use at your own risk

# Script to search a folder for redundant files and delete duplicates
# Unix directive of no news is good news is followed
# Usage: <path-to-script> FOLDER [Folder] [...]

# To create a test folder containing files:
# mkdir -p duplicates;
# for foo in {1..5}; do dd if=/dev/zero of=duplicates/$foo bs=4K count=$foo; done;
# cp duplicates/4 duplicates/4-copy

declare -A FILE_CKSUMS;

for FOLDER_TO_CHECK;
do
    [[ -d "${FOLDER_TO_CHECK}" ]] && [[ -w "${FOLDER_TO_CHECK}" ]] \
        &&
        {

            unset 'FILE_CKSUMS[@]';

            [[ "${FOLDER_TO_CHECK: -1}" != "/" ]] \
                && FOLDER_TO_CHECK="${FOLDER_TO_CHECK}/";

            # Globbing through the folder content
            for FILE_TO_CHECK in "${FOLDER_TO_CHECK}"*;
            do
                [[ -f "${FILE_TO_CHECK}" ]] && [[ -w "${FILE_TO_CHECK}" ]] \
                    &&
                    {
                        read -d ' ' FILE_CKSUM <<< `cksum "${FILE_TO_CHECK}"`;
                        [[ -n "${FILE_CKSUM}" ]] \
                            &&
                            {
                                [[ -n "${FILE_CKSUMS[${FILE_CKSUM}]}" ]] \
                                    &&
                                    {
                                        # Deleting file here
                                        rm "${FILE_TO_CHECK}" \
                                            || echo "Failed to delete file ${FILE_TO_CHECK}";
                                    } \
                                    ||
                                    {
                                        FILE_CKSUMS["${FILE_CKSUM}"]="${FILE_TO_CHECK}";
                                    }
                            }
                    }
            done
        }
done
```